# Как управлять очередью в вызовaх в qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Один поток соединяется с главным потоком с помощью флага
Qt::QueedConnection
Тоесть он не вызвает ф-ию главного потока, а добавляет ее в очередь, чтобы потом брать из очереди и вызывать. Но у меня бывает так, что добавляется в очередь больше чем удается обработать. Как быть?

на ум приходит только моячить из главного потока, если обработка не закончилась то не вздумай пихать на обработку еще...

Comment: Ответ зависит от того, каков практический смысл этих сообщений. Можно ли их игнорировать? Можно ли вместо двух вызовов слота выполнить один? При каких условиях? Этот слот - просто refresh, или в нем какая-то логическая работа?  Есть ли информация в параметрах слота? Можно ли отложить выполнение слота на заданное время?

Comment: если главный поток не успевает, значит ему дают слишком тяжелые задачи. Может нужно часть расчетов сделать в посылающем потоке? второе - это, отрисовка прогресса. Очень часто для максимального значения прогресса берут число как оно есть (например, размер файла в сотнях мегабайт) и на каждый обработанный байт отписываются. Вот только даже на 4к дисплее больше 4000 пикселей этот прогресс длинной не будет...нет смысла слать на каждый чих.

Answer (score 1):

Делал отслеживание входящих/исходящих данных вот таким образом:

```
bool MainWorker::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MetaCall)
    {
        QMetaCallEvent* metaEvent = static_cast<QMetaCallEvent*>(event);
        if (nullptr != dynamic_cast<const InputWorker*>(metaEvent->sender()))
        {
            ++m_queueCounter;
        }
        else if (nullptr != dynamic_cast<const OutputWorker*>(metaEvent->sender()))
        {
            if (--m_queueCounter == 0);
                emit imFreeForJob();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWorker принимает данные (через сигналы) от InputWorker-а, выполняет какую то тяжелую работу, после отдает результаты (опять через сигналы) в OutputWorker.
Обнуление счетчика говорит, что очередь пуста и можно посылать следующую пачку запросов.
Пачка запросов равнялась кол-ву потоков в системе, внутри MainWorker-а шло распараллеливание через QtConcurrent.

PS: для того чтобы использовать QEvent::MetaCall нужно подключать что то типа qevent_private.h, сейчас уже не помню точно.